# Search filter issues in Search Bar in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, swift4

```
let strArray :NSArray = self.filteredArray?.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSArray
```

The **error** showing in this line is:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1b5b8a800) to
>   'NSArray' (0x1b5b89950).

How can I change this one?

Comment: What is the value type stored in `filteredArray`?. According to the error it is `NSDictionary` and you're tying to force typecast it into `Array`

Comment: The first thing is to get rid of the force cast, use the `if let ... as? NSArray` syntax which will prevent this crash. After that you'll be able to pinpoint why you're trying to cast a `NSDictionary` into a `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```
let strArray : NSDictionary = self.filteredArray?.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary;
```

this error say "**Could not cast the actual type NSDictionary to the expected type NSArray**"